# Strange AutoLayout Behaviour or Bug with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

```
let cotnainer = UIView()
let item = UIView()
cotnainer.addSubview(item)
item.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.height.equalTo(item.snp_width)
    make.leading.trailing.equalTo(cotnainer).inset(8)
    make.top.bottom.equalTo(cotnainer)
}
print(cotnainer.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(CGSize(width: 375, height: 0), withHorizontalFittingPriority: 1000, verticalFittingPriority: 50))

let cellContainer = UITableViewCell()
let cellItem = UIView()
cellContainer.contentView.addSubview(cellItem)
cellItem.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.height.equalTo(cellItem.snp_width)
    make.leading.trailing.equalTo(cellContainer.contentView).inset(8)
    make.top.bottom.equalTo(cellContainer.contentView)
}
print(cellContainer.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(CGSize(width: 375, height: 0), withHorizontalFittingPriority: 1000, verticalFittingPriority: 50))
print(cellContainer.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(CGSize(width: 375, height: 0), withHorizontalFittingPriority: 1000, verticalFittingPriority: 50))
```

I am using SnapKit to make the constraints, and get back the result as follow.

```
(375.0, 359.0)
(375.0, 359.333333333333)
(375.0, 359.0)
```

I dont know why the 2nd result would have that extra 0.3333333 and this make my cell constraints to have error. Is this a bug or something that I am not setting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I print the subviews of UITableViewCell and found that it has a separator view, which is the cause of this strange behaviors.
set the `cellContainer.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` fix the problem